how to change base_link orientation as parent tf universal robot in moveit?
Affected ROS Driver version(s) : Ubuntu 20.04
Used ROS distribution : Noetic
Summary
I have a UR5e robot and a plan that contains a conveyor with the position as in the picture. I want to do cartesian movement from the camera coordinates. because the axis of the robot is tilted not parallel to the camera and conveyor so it is difficult to have a movement that is.
Issue details
If illustrated the movement of the robot and conveyor is like this. This is what makes it difficult for me to determine the algorithm to have coordinate equality between the camera and the robot. If you have a solution to this problem, please let me know.

whereas I have a fixed conveyor plan and don't want to change the axis of the conveyor.

I hope that the solution provided can make it easier to use the cartesian coordinates from moveit to convert to the tilted robot axis.
so I am looking for another solution so that the orientation of the robot can be rotated so that the robot axis will be parallel to the conveyor. If seen in the ROS transform (TF2) I can rotate the desired base_link frame but not change the position of the robot. when the program is run, the robot movement is still the same. after tracing something says if you want to change the parent TF because base_link is the parent TF.
need to change the urdf file so that all orientations of the robot can change. therefore I searched for the urdf file. only what was found was the guilty ur5e.srdf file from moveit.
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This does not replace URDF, and is not an extension of URDF.
    This is a format for representing semantic information about the robot structure.
    A URDF file must exist for this robot as well, where the joints and the links that are referenced are defined
-->
<robot name="ur5e_robot">
    <!--GROUPS: Representation of a set of joints and links. This can be useful for specifying DOF to plan for, defining arms, end effectors, etc-->
    <!--LINKS: When a link is specified, the parent joint of that link (if it exists) is automatically included-->
    <!--JOINTS: When a joint is specified, the child link of that joint (which will always exist) is automatically included-->
    <!--CHAINS: When a chain is specified, all the links along the chain (including endpoints) are included in the group. Additionally, all the joints that are parents to included links are also included. This means that joints along the chain and the parent joint of the base link are included in the group-->
    <!--SUBGROUPS: Groups can also be formed by referencing to already defined group names-->
    <group name="manipulator">
        <chain base_link="base_link" tip_link="tool0"/>
    </group>
    <!--GROUP STATES: Purpose: Define a named state for a particular group, in terms of joint values. This is useful to define states like 'folded arms'-->
    <group_state name="home" group="manipulator">
        <joint name="elbow_joint" value="-1.5685"/>
        <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint" value="-1.3713"/>
        <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint" value="0.7613"/>
        <joint name="wrist_1_joint" value="-1.8231"/>
        <joint name="wrist_2_joint" value="1.5452"/>
        <joint name="wrist_3_joint" value="-1.6346"/>
    </group_state>
    <group_state name="up" group="manipulator">
        <joint name="elbow_joint" value="0"/>
        <joint name="shoulder_lift_joint" value="-1.5707"/>
        <joint name="shoulder_pan_joint" value="0"/>
        <joint name="wrist_1_joint" value="-1.5707"/>
        <joint name="wrist_2_joint" value="0"/>
        <joint name="wrist_3_joint" value="0"/>
    </group_state>
    <!--VIRTUAL JOINT: Purpose: this element defines a virtual joint between a robot link and an external frame of reference (considered fixed with respect to the robot)-->
    <virtual_joint name="fixed_base" type="fixed" parent_frame="world" child_link="base_link"/>
    <!--DISABLE COLLISIONS: By default it is assumed that any link of the robot could potentially come into collision with any other link in the robot. This tag disables collision checking between a specified pair of links. -->
    <disable_collisions link1="base_link_inertia" link2="shoulder_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="forearm_link" link2="upper_arm_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="forearm_link" link2="wrist_1_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="forearm_link" link2="wrist_2_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="shoulder_link" link2="upper_arm_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_1_link" link2="wrist_2_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_1_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Never"/>
    <disable_collisions link1="wrist_2_link" link2="wrist_3_link" reason="Adjacent"/>
</robot>

and the ur5e_macro.xacro file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <!--
    Convenience wrapper for the 'ur_robot' macro which provides default values
    for the various "parameters files" parameters for a UR5e.

    This file can be used when composing a more complex scene with one or more
    UR5e robots.

    While the generic 'ur_robot' macro could also be used, it would require
    the user to provide values for all parameters, as that macro does not set
    any model-specific defaults (not even for the generic parameters, such as
    the visual and physical parameters and joint limits).

    Refer to the main 'ur_macro.xacro' in this package for information about
    use, contributors and limitations.

    NOTE: users will most likely want to override *at least* the
          'kinematics_parameters_file' parameter. Otherwise, a default kinematic
          model will be used, which will almost certainly not correspond to any
          real robot.
  -->
  <xacro:macro name="ur5e_robot" params="
   prefix
   joint_limits_parameters_file:='$(find ur_description)/config/ur5e/joint_limits.yaml'
   kinematics_parameters_file:='$(find ur_description)/config/ur5e/default_kinematics.yaml'
   physical_parameters_file:='$(find ur_description)/config/ur5e/physical_parameters.yaml'
   visual_parameters_file:='$(find ur_description)/config/ur5e/visual_parameters.yaml'
   transmission_hw_interface:=hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface
   safety_limits:=false
   safety_pos_margin:=0.15
   safety_k_position:=20"
  >
    <xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/inc/ur_macro.xacro"/>
    <xacro:ur_robot
      prefix="${prefix}"
      joint_limits_parameters_file="${joint_limits_parameters_file}"
      kinematics_parameters_file="${kinematics_parameters_file}"
      physical_parameters_file="${physical_parameters_file}"
      visual_parameters_file="${visual_parameters_file}"
      transmission_hw_interface="${transmission_hw_interface}"
      safety_limits="${safety_limits}"
      safety_pos_margin="${safety_pos_margin}"
      safety_k_position="${safety_k_position}"
    />
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>

I don't see a base_link orientation that can be changed. I would appreciate any answers.

in the end I had to rotate the robot to get the same coordinates as the moveit downloaded on the site https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver. I have tried several steps such as changing the orientation on ur_common or creating a parent tf on base_link, but it is not the base_link that rotates but the parent tf. I see that from the installation of ur_driver is quite rigid in changing the urdf
